# InDesign: which export settings for printing an A5 booklet

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, print-production

Getting a 48-page booklet professionally printed. The printing company states we should export as PDF (x1 a 2001) with fonts converted to outlines, but is that necessary? Also should it be exported in pages or spreads?

Comment: If the printer says its required, I'd say yes it's necessary if you want them to print it. These are really questions you should be asking your printer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should export this as single pages (not spreads). As for the other export settings, you should use your printing company's requirements.

As a general rule, its not always necessary to convert the fonts to outlines, nor is it necessary to use the 'x1 a 2001' standard. Most printers can handle any kind of high res export, but if they do make specific requirements, you should follow these to make sure they wont have any problems.

I do admit however that converting a 48-page document to outlines is a bit unusual, but they must have their reasons.